# Maven Common dependencies multiple projects exclude jar from war

Tags: maven, dependencies, myeclipse

We have multiple web projects(100+), custom jars and REST web service projects in our environment. We were using ANT to build with Jboss5.2.1 and I am trying to move to Maven with MyEclipse 2019 and deploy to a Tomcat server. All of the common jars required are in Jboss/server/default/lib and are added into the build path of the web project. We do not want the dependency jars to be packaged into the WAR files. With Maven, the dependencies get added to the war increasing the size of the war. We would like to have these dependencies like gson, poi, etc in a common place and refer to that using build path. Is that a possibility?

I did read about using system scope. But since that is deprecated and not suggested, I do not want to go that route. Setting up a local maven repository with a parent project also does not seem to be something that will work for us because I do not want the dependency jar in the lib folder of the WAR.

Is going with Maven even the right approach in this case? MyEclipse CI 2019 creates all web projects as Maven projects by default. So I will have to figure out a way to disable that if this is not the right build tool for us.

Having the dependency jars packaged into the WAR is something that will not be accepted here since the deployment team feels that bloats the size of each WAR unnecessarily. I am new to Maven and trying to setup the project the right way. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Global libraries is usually a bad approach which the part server/default/lib exactly is. Usually a war should be packaged and contain everything which is needed. Furthermore do you need the JBoss server or are you doing two things. Moving away from Ant going from JBoss into Tomcat only ? – khmarbaise 7 mins ago

Comment: We are moving away from JBoss and going to Tomcat. We had EJBs previously, but we are moving in the direction of using REST webservices. Having war with everything increases the size of the war, thereby increasing the server startup time. Since we have 100+ wars, that adds up over time. Can you please elaborate on why global libraries are a bad approach?

Comment: I didn't wrote the war should contain everything. It should have only what is really needed. If you like to REST services each service should be independent of each other and basic idea of REST services (micro services?) is the share nothing principle...If you have several libs as shared you need to tests each change for all of the services...no option to change a lib for a single service where the real problem is located. So furthermore going to Tomcat would be a good idea to think about Spring Boot which exactly contains Tomcat etc. .and makes development more easy etc. (testing etc.)..

Comment: Thank you for explaining! However, is there a way to achieve this when using Maven? Each REST service will be independent of each other, however we would like to have the jars shared in a common place.

Comment: If it matters, in the latest versions of MyEclipse, we've forced Java EE 8 projects to be Maven based, but you still have a choice for earlier Java EE versions. We made this decision because we found most users using Maven anyway, and the likelihood of it being used for a new Java EE 8 project is quite high. 

Quite sure it's possible to achieve what you want with Maven, and it's probably the best tool for the job anyway. Unfortunately it's not too easy to be more specific without understanding your application's architecture, project relationships, etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! We are okay with using Maven, however we need to be able to use the dependency jars like gson, poi, etc from Tomcat/shared lib rather than packaging them into the war, thereby increasing the size of the war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want some common jars to be provided by the server at runtime and not be packaged into each war.

So you have to do two things:

- Add the jars to your server (Jboss/Tomcat) so that they are available at runtime.
- Add the jars as `provided` dependencies for the wars that need them. This means that you define a dependency on them but set the `<scope>provided</provided>`.

This has the effect that the dependencies are available at compile time but are not bundled into the war.

Beware, though, that having many common libraries makes it hard to update one of those.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I added the jars to Tomcat/lib/SharedFolder and included that under shared.loader in catalina.properties.